# Open 2 windows with set timeout

Tags: javascript

I have this code that redirect the current window and also open another popup window. I need the current window to be opened first and then the pop up window for user to do something. but what it is doing is open the current window and then the pop up window, but then it goes back to the current window and doesn't stay with popup window. how do I make it stay with popup window.

```
 var WindowFtrs = "menubar=no,location=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=no,width=600,height=630";      
          document.location.href =  lUrl + RPID;             
  setTimeout(window.open(rUrl+ "?PID=" + RPID + isDlg , "Mywindow", WindowFtrs),5000);
```

Comment: Beware that if the window is not opened as the result of the user triggered event, the popupblocker will likely block it.

Comment: And your structure's going to have to be `setTimeout(function () { window.open(blah blah...); }, 5000);`

Comment: And so what is the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Change its `target` argument for '_blank'.

`window.open(url,target,params)`

Comment: I do n't have a problem with the target?